# search via fnServerData in datatables plugin issue

Tags: jquery, datatable

i want to pass data to server page to search with,i echo/print query on server file which do not concatenate where if i provide more than one parameters.it only shows last provided param in where.here is my code

```
"fnServerData": function ( sSource, aoData, fnCallback ) {
                            /* Add some extra data to the sender */
                            aoData.push( 
                             { "name": "type", "value": $('#type_dummy').val() },
                             { "name": "category_id", "value": $('#category_id').val() },
                             { "name": "region_id", "value": $('#region_id').val() }

                            );

                            $.getJSON( sSource, aoData, function (json) { 
                                /* Do whatever additional processing you want on the callback, then tell DataTables */
                                fnCallback(json)

                } );
            }
```

on server side processing file i have this

```
$sWhere = "";
if ( $_GET['sSearch'] != "" )
{
    $sWhere = "WHERE (";
    for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
    {
        $sWhere .= $aColumns[$i]." LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string( $_GET['sSearch'] )."%' OR ";
    }
    $sWhere = substr_replace( $sWhere, "", -3 );
    $sWhere .= ')';
}

/* Individual column filtering */
for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
{
    if ( $_GET['bSearchable_'.$i] == "true" && $_GET['sSearch_'.$i] != '' )
    {
        if ( $sWhere == "" )
        {
            $sWhere = "WHERE ";
        }
        else
        {
            $sWhere .= " AND ";
        }
        $sWhere .= $aColumns[$i]." LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['sSearch_'.$i])."%' ";
    }
}

 if(isset($_GET['type'])  && $_GET['type'] != '' ){
$sWhere = "WHERE rent.type = '$_GET[type]' ";
 }
  if(isset($_GET['category_id'])  && $_GET['category_id'] != '' ){
$sWhere = "WHERE rent.category_id = '$_GET[category_id]' ";
 }
```

i run this server side file directly in url and pass both parameters in url and print query,it only shows one param in where like my link is

```
/view_match_lead_server.php?type=1&category_id=1
```

query's where  is like this(other query is ok )

```
WHERE category_id=1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this Question is still active:

Three steps / issues:

I have just resolved the same issue. Where you are using "fnServerData() with three parameters, I used fnServerParams() with only one parameter - the aoData. My three additional parameters in aoData.push are similar to yours.

Secondly, I use Firebug to ensure that I am sending my additional parameters in the URL for $_GET to obtain correctly. It is essential to clear the History in the browser to ensure that this is not interfering with your changes.

Finally I have a comprehensive Class Function which does the Server PHP bit, so it would be difficult (but not impossible) to use that as a solution to your Server Script. If this Question is still active and unresolved, I will provide a more detailed analysis of your PHP Script.